# Chrome renders vertical line on mouseover

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-transitions

[Example website](http://www.patrickcason.com)

So when you mouseover the projects you should see an rgba background fade in with some text over the existing image.  I cannot duplicate the error in Safari or in Firefox.  In fact, I cannot duplicate this for the same ones every time, and I can also say that refreshing the page will not necessarily fix the problem either.

Is this a problem in my code or have we come upon a problem with Webkit and/or Chrome specifically?

**UPDATE 1**

Originally I thought this was a problem with the RGBA background so I tried using a `background: black;` to see if it changed anything.  This didn't work seeing as the line was still present on mouseover.

**UPDATE 2**

I have considered this to be a problem due to the display I've been using.  I'm on the new Macbook Pro with retina display.  This could still be the source of the issue, but I'm not convinced it is.  I'm yet to do testing myself on another device that isn't a retina display, but I've been told that the lines are still prevalent.

**This image will help:**

[image: Here's a fun image description!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something about your box-model that I don't like for this technique. I've used similar hover/fade scripts, but never utilized a negative margin (because it will jack up the box-model), or made the top layer larger than the bottom.

I found a few things that helped it render better for me (I'm wasn't seeing lines, but I was seeing either rounded white corners peaking out or black chisel points in the parent corners). At any rate, here's the few things:

1. Nix the -1% 0 0 -1% margin (making something 102% wide, then using a -1% margin seems like 100% to me, but relies on all browsers rendering that math the same).
2. Set the parent and child to be the same W x H (200px x 410px)
3. Decreasing the radius of the child by one px hid the oddities of the corners for me (again, I think it's a rendering engine thing FWIW); though not having it set should do the job.
4. I also add `.projectItem a:hover` to the `.projectItem a`'s CSS declaration, to allow just the transitions to occur on `.projectItem a:hover`.

This fiddle does the roll-over effect with all the features above added/removed respectively: http://jsfiddle.net/hd4QM/

HTH.

Comment: Wow, Dawson... perfect answer.  Fixed everything completely!  Thanks so much for your help and for the jsFiddle!

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce *le problem* in Chrome, but from your screenshot it looks like you are zoomed in. Sometimes browsers round off percentages and you might be ending up with a missing pixel, it's best to make it *stick* to each edge instead of specifying height and width:

```
.projectItem {
  overflow: hidden;
 }

 .projectItem a {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   opacity: 0;
   width: 102%;
   height: 102%;
   background: black;
   color: #F6F8EE;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
   border-radius: 5px;
   margin: -1% 0 0 -1%;
 }
```

Also, I'm not sure why you're displaying as `table`, but this might be compounding the problem. Change it to `block`.

Comment: I'm actually not zoomed in, I'm using a retina display.

Comment: I can also confirm that changing the style to `block` does not fix the problem, but that is the correct display and I've changed it thusly.  Also, I find that changing the width and height from 100% to their respective values doesn't fix the problem either.

Comment: I could reproduce it earlier - only for a fraction of a second when the links are first hovered - but now I cannot. OP, if you changed something, maybe that's your fix?

Comment: The only workaround that occurs to me is exceeding the dimensions of the parent container, try with the updated answer.

Comment: I have tried your updated example Duopixel to no success: http://i.imgur.com/t3hA4.jpg  I'm beginning to think this might be a problem due to Chrome not working well with my retina display.

Comment: Then let it overflow the parent div by exceeding the dimensions, but apply `overflow: hidden` to `.projectItem`. If this doesn't work then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: This doesn't exactly fix the issue, but it certainly works better than before.  I removed the RGBA and just did straight black as a background and was given the same results.  I feel this is not an issue of RGBA, but rather how Chrome renders some site elements on a retina device.  I've changed by question therefore.  If I don't get a better response soon then the answer belongs to you Duopixel.  Thanks!

Comment: Your answer, wasn't correct, but +1 for sticking with it and trying hard to help me out.